# Font and space change for section heading

Tags: fonts, spacing, sectioning, koma-script

I have changed the `section` defination to get section title inside a `colorbox`. Now, I can't use `titlesec` to change varticle spacing around the section header, specially on top of it.
Also, I want to change the section title font to `Roboto`.

This is my `mwe`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext,xcolor}
% Colorbox for section title
\colorlet{sectioncolor}{orange}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \colorbox{sectioncolor}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
      \raggedsection\color{white}\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
}}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}   ! Want Roboto for Section Title only
\begin{document}
\section*{Bar}
\blindtext
\section*{Foo}

\end{document}
```

How I can get that? I use `lualatex` for compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical space before and after section header can be changed by

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1.5em,% <- before section header
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=1em,% <- after section header
  runin=false
]{section}
```

If only the section titles should use Roboto:

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Roboto{Roboto}
\addtokomafont{section}{\Roboto}% Roboto only for section titles
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}% a4paper is default
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Colorbox for section title
\colorlet{sectioncolor}{orange}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \colorbox{sectioncolor}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
      \raggedsection\color{white}\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Roboto{Roboto}
\addtokomafont{section}{\Roboto}% Roboto only for section titles

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1.5em,% <- before section header
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=1em,% <- after section header
  runin=false
]{section}

\begin{document}
\section*{Bar}
\blindtext
\section*{Foo}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]